# while loop - sum of even numbers and its average

Tags: java

http://pastebin.com/w8KntkE6#

```
package javaapplication9;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        {
            int sum = 0, num, count = 0;
            double average;

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter an integer (0 to quit): ");
            num = scan.nextInt();

            while (num >= 0) // sentinel num of 0 to terminate loop
            {
                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                    count++;
                    sum += num;
                    System.out.println("The sum so far is " + sum);

                    System.out.print("Enter an integer (0 to quit): ");
                    num = scan.nextInt();
                } else if (num % 2 != 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.println();

                if (count == 0) {
                    System.out.println("No nums were entered.");
                } else {
                    average = (double)sum / count;

                    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
                    System.out.println("The average is " + fmt.format(average));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The code executes and it sums even numbers. However, when a odd number enters it returns an error or it breaks. I want it ignore any odd number. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: "it returns an error". How so? Is there an exception? Or what is the output of your program in the error case?
And by the way there is one parentheses missing in your code example, it won't compile that way - should there be a parenthesis before `System.out.println();`?

Answer (score 2):

You `continue` the loop on odd numbers without modifying `num` - looks like it should infinite loop to me.

Comment: No. Those items won't work. I tried it. Even if I add an else if (num % 2 != 0){
    continue;
}

to

else if (num % 2 !=0){
        num = scan.nextInt();
        continue;
    }

Comment: Your `continue` bounces you straight back to the top of the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something, or are you missing a `nextInt()` when you have an odd number? Since in the if even you have `num = scan.nextInt();`. You don't when num is odd.
Change

```
else if (num % 2 != 0){
    continue;
}
```

to

```
else if (num % 2 !=0){
    num = scan.nextInt();
    continue;
}
```

Comment: If a number is odd, I want it to ignore the odd number and keep continuing. In the end, I want it to only sum the even numbers.

Comment: Try printing the number before your if statement... Then you'll see the number is not added...
Or remove num = scan.nextInt() from your else if part to just after the 'while' statement. Anywho, make sure this procedure (nextInt) is called, otherwise you have, essentially, a while(true) loop

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
package javaapplication9;


import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication9 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    {
        int sum = 0, num, count = 0;
        double average;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an integer (0 to quit): ");
        num = scan.nextInt();

        while (num >= 0) // sentinel num of 0 to terminate loop
        {
            if (num % 2 == 0)
            {
                count++;

                sum += num;
                System.out.println("The sum so far is " + sum);

                System.out.print("Enter an integer (0 to quit): ");
                num = scan.nextInt();            

               if (count == 0) {
                 System.out.println("No nums were entered.");
               } else {
                 average = (double) sum / count;
                 DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
                 System.out.println("The average is " + fmt.format(average));
               }
          }              
          num = scan.nextInt();               
      }
}
```

Comment: Actually I want it to be an infinite loop until a user enters a negative number. It breaks when you enter an odd number. :( with your code. It just gives you the average.

Answer (score 0):

just before continue statement add following code. I hope it will work correctly.

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer (0 to quit): ");
            num = scan.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not quite sure when do you want to print the average, you could move it out of the while loop if you want to print it at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    {
        int sum = 0, num, count = 0;
        double average;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an integer (0 to quit): ");

        while ((num = scan.nextInt())> 0) // sentinel num of 0 to terminate loop
        {
            if (num % 2 == 0){
                count++;

                sum += num;
                System.out.println("The sum so far is " + sum);
                if (count == 0) {
                    System.out.println("No nums were entered.");
                } else {
                    average = (double) sum / count;

                    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
                    System.out.println("The average is " + fmt.format(average));
                }
            }

            System.out.print("Enter an integer (0 to quit): ");

        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```